# Best way to move ranking from one domain to another

Tags: google, ranking, google-ranking

Domain learn-blazor.com appears on the first page in Google given a specific search word (Blazor), whereas site my site (blazor-university.com) appears on the 5th page.

learn-blazor.com is an abandoned site and I've been offered ownership of it and its content. What is the best thing I can do to with learn-blazor.com to improve the ranking of blazor-university.com?

1. Redirect pages on it to the relevant page on my site?
2. Put links in its pages to the relevant page on my site?
3. Return something in a header?
4. Something else?

Comment: That domain doesn't rank on the first page, it's content does. Once you change the content associated with that domain that ranking will change

Comment: To be clear, you own Domain X but you don't own any of Domain X's content, right? Or did you purchase the entire website?

Comment: Domain and content

Comment: What does the backlink profile look like for each?

Comment: @Trebor I have added domain names to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, first it's important to remember what John has already said.  It's your content that ranks, not your domain name per se.

That said, it looks as though your newly acquired domain has quite a few backlinks (moz.com) and ranks for several key words.  Assuming your own site has similar content and you want it to rank for the same key words, I would implement 301 Permanent Redirects.

Per [Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection),

> "A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of
>   link equity (ranking power) to the redirected page. "

While you will pass some link juice, you won't "move" the domain rank, just pass some of the juice.

If your content isn't similar and all you're trying to do is capture users searching for the name, you might not get any benefit from a 301 as users will come to your site and immediately leave when they don't find what they were looking for.  That will hurt your rankings.

That leaves you with a choice of buying the domain to keep it from competitors.  You could also use it as an additional domain that points users to your current domain via the content.

You could also take some pages from your own domain, and copy them to the new domain with canonical links back to the original pages.  You might also reach out to those who created back links to the new domain and ask them to change them to your domain.

I don't think you're going to be able to simply pick up the domain rank from domain A and move it to domain B.  My guess is that it's going to take lots of little steps.

There's probably others here who have additional ideas.

Comment: That worked brilliantly. I've moved from about the 5th page to the 5th result!

Comment: @PeterMorris, I assume you mean you did the 301 redirect? or did you do something else?  Glad you were able to up your ranking.

Comment: Yes, 301. For the phrase "learn blazor" I am now ranked first. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.